# Angular class @ViewChild property is not accessible in class method

Tags: angular, class, components, viewchild

I have an Angular component class, and inside the `openModal()` method I has no access to the @ViewChild `content` property, but strange enough, and as `static:true` no such problem is inside even `ngOnInit()` and `ngAfterViewInit()`. I have done the homework, so if I put the `this.modalService.open(this.content)` line inside these callbacks, all work perfectly, but if the line in `openModal()` the modal opens with no content (ja certainly). I am already significantly contributed to the climate change googling it:

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit, TemplateRef, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {NgbModalConfig, NgbModal} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal-auto-shown',
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
  providers: [NgbModalConfig, NgbModal]
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('content', {static: true}) private content: any;
  private test = 'test_string';

  constructor(config: NgbModalConfig, private modalService: NgbModal) {
    config.backdrop = 'static';
    config.keyboard = false;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('oninit this:', this);
    console.log('oninit this.test:', this.test);
    console.log('oninit this.content:', this.content);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('afterviewinit this:', this);
    console.log('afterviewinit  this.test:', this.test);
    console.log('afterviewinit  this.content:', this.content);
  }

  openModal(that = this) {
    console.log('openmodal this:', this);
    console.log('openmodal  this.test:', this.test);
    console.log('openmodal  this.content:', this.content);
    console.log('openmodal this:', that);
    console.log('openmodal  that.test:', that.test);
    console.log('openmodal  that.content:', that.content);
    console.log('openmodal that === this:', that === this);
    this.modalService.open(this.content);
    that.modalService.open(that.content);
  }

}
```

I dump here the console:

```
oninit this: ModalComponent {modalService: NgbModal, test: "test_string", content: TemplateRef_}  
oninit this.test: test_string   
oninit this.content: TemplateRef_ {_parentView: {…}, _def: {…}}  
afterviewinit this: ModalComponent {modalService: NgbModal, test: "test_string", content: TemplateRef_}  
afterviewinit this.test: test_string  
afterviewinit this.content: TemplateRef_ {_parentView: {…}, _def: {…}}  

openmodal this: ModalComponent {modalService: NgbModal, test: "test_string"}  
openmodal this.test: test_string  
openmodal this.content: undefined  
openmodal this: ModalComponent {modalService: NgbModal, test: "test_string"}  
openmodal that.test: test_string  
openmodal that.content: undefined  
openmodal that === this: true
```

the `test` property just lives happily after, it is accessible from all methods, however, the @ChildView property not, and this is not related to the context variable `this` (??). What daemon is here under the hood?

Comment: brother when you are printing content you have used `that.content` in your code so remove `that = this` from `openModal()` and better use it without `that`, i guess its referencing problem

Comment: Unfortunately, `this` without `that` is the same behavior, `that` is there to prove that the global and local `this` still has no `content` property. But agree somehow around "that" :)

Answer (score 0):

[As Angular docs says:](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild#description)

> static - True to resolve query results before change detection runs

In addition, the `{ static: true }` [allow users to define timing of ViewChild/ContentChild queries](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/28810):

> With this commit, users can dictate when they want a particular
>   ViewChild or ContentChild query to be resolved with the static flag.
>   For example, one can mark a particular query as static: false to
>   ensure change detection always runs before its results are set:
>
> @ContentChild('foo', {static: false}) foo !: ElementRef; This means
>   that even if there isn't a query result wrapped in an
>   *ngIf or an *ngFor now, adding one to the template later won't change the timing of the query resolution and potentially break your
>   component.
>
> Similarly, if you know that your query needs to be resolved earlier
>   (e.g. you need results in an ngOnInit hook), you can mark it as
>   static: true.
>
> @ViewChild(TemplateRef, {static: true}) foo !: TemplateRef; Note: this
>   means that your component will not support *ngIf results.
>
> If you do not supply a static option when creating your ViewChild or
>   ContentChild query, the default query resolution timing will kick in.
>
> Note: This new option only applies to ViewChild and ContentChild
>   queries, not ViewChildren or ContentChildren queries, as those types
>   already resolve after CD runs.

Comment: Ok. I was aware. But `static:false` renders only `oninit this.content:` to be undefined, all others are the same.

Comment: @user1229873 could you create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) example?